# HTML textbox, auto highlighting text

Tags: html, text, highlight

How would I make a textbox, containing preexisting text, that when the user clicked within it all the text inside it would become highlighted. For example, the same way YouTube does the textboxes for the embed code on their videos. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If I've understood your problem correctly, you could use some javascript (untested code):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function selectText(textField) 
  {
    textField.focus();
    textField.select();
  }
</script>

<input type="text" name="sometext" size="100" value="The Text" onClick='selectText(this);'>
```

You can put the script between your <head> and </head> tags.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Quick followup, I want to put some javascript to be copy and pasted within the textbox, but it seems to be messing it up, is there a way to do this with javascript text inside it?

Comment: nm I got it, a simple double quote to single quote seems to have fixed it.

Comment: To keep normal functionality, I'd add a guard to only `selectText()` on mouseup if (1) no other text is selected or (2) was selected on mousedown.

Comment: the meat of this is just the `.select();`, it can be implemented however you want, normally I'd use `document.getElementById` as opposed to setting an HTML element equal to a variable