# How do I make auto select text in HTML

Tags: html, text

I have a further question about a solution provided elsewhere on this site ([HTML textbox, auto highlighting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736158/html-textbox-auto-highlighting-text/736176#736176))

The solution for making auto select text worked, but I can't figure out how to include HTML in the box, without it disappearing. I have used the text on the following page:

http://www.tennessee-scv.org/camp1640/Tour/media/

For example, I need the first box to read:

```
<a href="http://www.germantowntour.com" target="_blank">Germantown Tour</a>
```

but if I set it up like that, then it it only displays up to the first ("), so I had to use (').

Answer (score 1):

This is what you require!!

```
<textarea name="textarea" cols="85" rows="10" wrap="VIRTUAL" onclick="this.select();">CODE HERE!!/textarea>
```

Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/qNmXr/8/

Updated Fiddle Link. This is the exact thing which works for you. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&quot;`

```
<a href=&quot;http://www.germantowntour.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Germantown Tour</a>
```

[W3c reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#double-quote-attr)